# Use query results to insert into second table - Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am creating an application using code igniter and I am having trouble inserting rows into a table based on the results from a query.

What I want to do is select a set of tasks based on a job and then insert those tasks into a table which records if it has been completed or not e.g.

```
Table Tasks
TaskID TaskGroup TaskDesc
1      WashCar    Get Bucket
2      WashCar    Fill with Water
3      WashCar    Add Soap
4      PolishCar  Get Buffer
5      PolishCar  Get Polish
6      PolishCar  Get Power Lead
```

So what the user does is fill in a form and select the type of Job that are going to go e.g. Wash Car or Polish Car and then what I want to do is get a list of all the task ID's that relate to Wash Car and insert them into a Work Table which records if that task has been done or not e.g.

```
Work Table
WorkID TaskID TaskDate TaskComplete
1      1      01/01/2015 N
2      2      01/01/2015 N
3      3      01/01/2015 N
```

At the moment when I submit the form all the other tables are populated but my work table is not being populated - no errors it just doesnt get populated.

This is what I currently have in my model (that I have pieced together from other Stack Overflow questions):

```
$workDueDate = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('14 days'));
$creator4 = $this->session->userdata('logged_in');
$wkCreator = $creator4['id']; 
$workCreator = $wkCreator;
$workCreateDate = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
$this -> db -> select('taskid');
$this -> db -> from('task');
$this -> db -> where ('taskgroup','washcar');
$this -> db -> order_by('taskid', 'asc');
$workQuery = $this -> db -> get();
return $workQuery->result_array();
for($i=0; $i<$workQuery;$i++){
$insertWork = array(
                    'taskid' => $workQuery[$i],
                    'taskdate' => $workDueDate,
                    'taskcomplete' => 'N',
                    );
   $this->db->insert('work_w',$insertWork);
        }
```

As you can see I am very new to this and having some problems getting this to work.  This is the latest iteration, I have tried foreach loops and I cant seem to get it to work.

Does anyone have any thoughts on what I am doing wrong here or how best to acheieve this?

Thanks

EDIT

Updated code:

```
$workDueDate = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('14 days'));
$creator4 = $this->session->userdata('logged_in');
$wkCreator = $creator4['id']; 
$workCreator = $wkCreator;
$workCreateDate = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
$this -> db -> select('taskid');
$this -> db -> from('task');
$this -> db -> where ('taskgroup','washcar');
$this -> db -> order_by('taskid', 'asc');
$workQuery = $this -> db -> get();
foreach ($workQuery as $wtid){
        $insertWork = array(
                'taskid' => $wtid['taskid'],
                'taskdate' => $workDueDate,
                'taskcomplete' => 'N',
                );
        $this->db->insert('work_w',$insertWork);
  }
```

Comment: return $workQuery->result_array(); where is this comming from

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As other users mentioned, you have an extra `return` right before your loop.

But this is not the right way to do this task. First of all it is all data-related so you better do that in a stored procedure in your database instead of PHP. Second, it is possible to achieve the same result without using a loop at all:

```
INSERT INTO work_w
(taskid, taskdate, taskcomplete)
SELECT task_id, date_add(CURRENT_DATE, INTERVAL 14 DAY), 'N'
FROM task
WHERE taskgroup = 'washcar'
ORDER BY taskid
```

Comment: The example I gave above wasnt the exact example I am working on, just an easier way for me to explain what I was trying to achieve.  In actual fact there are approx 7 columns and one of them gets the user ID from the session.  You could be right though, it may be possible to use a Stored Proc to populate this table and get the user ID from the other tables that get populated.  Where would you call a stored Proc - Model or Controller?

Comment: Model. It might be still possible to use a single SQL statement instead of a stored procedure. Avoid iterating records.

Comment: How would you write a SQL statement like that using Active record in Codeigniter?

Comment: Active Record is not suited for such queries. Use $this->db->query(...);

Comment: Thank you very much for your help on this. Using a query is working very well now.  Wasted so much time on this so happy to have finally got past it! Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

The problem is this:

```
return $workQuery->result_array();
```

You're leaving the function before the next loop starts. Remove the `return` line (or move it to the end) and then the loop will run.

Comment: This has definitely helped so thank you.  What I have done now is go back to a foreach loop but interestingly I am now getting double the amount of rows populated in the work table e.g. 8 instead of 4 and the task ID is not being populated (almost seems like the query fails).  I will edit the question with updated code.

Answer (score 0):

Couldnt get the loop to work, but as pointed out it was probably not the best way to go about this.

I have now gone for a query (this -> db -> query () ) and I am populating the work table perfectly now.